# Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a question regarding how to retrieve the value of href from android webview.

E.g. I have this 
`<a id="test" href="wwww.test123.com">Test123</a>` in the webpage.

The question is how am i going to retrieve the "www.test123.com" in android webview?

E.g. `String testHref = "www.test123.com"` ---> this value retrieve from the web page and being assigned to one of the variables in webview.

***Note: I do not have any control to the web page. So, I cannot modify any codes on the web page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying this code to get content in web
I have no ideal what you mean "assigned to one of the variables in webview." If you mean redirection, just do view.loadUrl(url)
Hope it help!

```
    class MyJavaScriptInterface {;

        public MyJavaScriptInterface(TextView aContentView) {
            mContentView = aContentView;
            Log.e(TAG, "get " + (mContentView == null ? true : false));
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processContent(String aContent)
        {
            final String content = aContent;
            mContentView.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // this is what you load from web
                    Log.i(TAG, content);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(contentView), "INTERFACE");
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript: window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);");
            Log.v(TAG, "onPageFinish");
            String WebViewUrl = myBrowser.getUrl();
            Log.e(TAG, WebViewUrl);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives me the idea on how to solve my problem.